# Python standalone on linux: No module named qgis.core

Tags: qgis, python, ubuntu, standalone

I am using the Spyder IDE on my Ubuntu LTS 16.04. It does not find the module qgis.core. Therefore I wanted to manually add it to its search path but I do not now where it is located. What is the default path to that module on ubuntu?
I am using QGis 2.16

EDIT:
I tried to add this path:
`/usr/share/qgis/python` but it did not help

EDIT_2:
I've printed out my sys.path to show me all paths considered by the interpreter:

`['', '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/core', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/matt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/matt/.ipython']`

Do I miss something important there?